# Using the go-fuse package in Golang

Tags: go, fuse

Hello I'm about to port my two almost working simple fuse filesystems from [bazillion fuse](https://github.com/bazillion/fuse) to go-fuse.  [go-fuse api](https://godoc.org/github.com/hanwen/go-fuse/fuse) seems more complex.
The question is:

1. In `NewServer()`, which RawFileSystem to use?
2. How to implement callbacks for read, readdir etc.?
3. Where to use `WaitMount()`?
4. What are `DeleteNotify()`, `EntryNotify()`?

Comment: my current is here https://github.com/goen/goenfuse/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found the solutions

1.
make a struct that contains nodefs.Node:

```
    type my_root struct {nodefs.Node}
```

initialize it

```
    my = &my_root{Node: nodefs.NewDefaultNode()}
```

make a connection and a raw filesystem

```
    con := nodefs.NewFileSystemConnector(my, nil)
    raw := fuse.NewRawFileSystem(con.RawFS())
```

finally, fire up the fuse fs

```
    server, err := fuse.NewServer(raw, f.dir, optz)
```

2. like this:

   ```
   func (my_root) OpenDir(context *fuse.Context) ([]fuse.DirEntry, fuse.Status) {}
   func (my_root) Lookup(out *fuse.Attr, name string, context *fuse.Context) (node *nodefs.Inode, code fuse.Status)
   ```
3. after step 1, like this:

   ```
   server.WaitMount()
   ```
4. i didn't need this.